# How to make a specific characters of word bold?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to make specific characters of string bold. For example I have a string:

"Hello Dev! How are you?"

In this I want to make character D of Dev bold.

I can do this using Formatted string like this way:

```cs
 <Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="Hello" />
            <Span Text=" D" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            <Span Text="ev!" />
            <Span Text=" How are you?" />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

But here lies the problem. I have to perform this with localisation. That is text will come in 3 different languages. In that place of word get changed.

Another problem is I have to divide string in many small parts. So does anyone know how we can achieve this using Converter or any other way, where we don't have to split the string in small parts.

Comment: You want only "D" or every first char of a word? or the first char of the second word (which is D" in this case)

Comment: Yes, I only want to make D bold. It can be at anywhere in the string, i.e. it can be at start, or it can be at in between or it can be end of the string.

Comment: It sounds like you need a way to indicate in your localized string that part of it can be bold. E.g. `"Hello *D*ev"` or `"Hello <b>D</b>ev"`. Then have a custom converter which parses this into a `FormattedString`, creating the necessary spans

Comment: I have tried to make converter that can return spans, but the problem is FormattedString property does not have setter value its only have getter. @canton7

Comment: @Divyesh_08 I said the converter should return a `FormattedString`?

Comment: @canton7 Yes, thanks for the suggestion, I have got the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Junior Jiang thanks for sharing your idea, it does work.

But I have got my solution with Converter. I am sharing my solution here, so that it can be helpful to someone looking for same.

**StringToFormattedTextConverter**

```cs
public class StringToFormattedTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return new FormattedString();
            }
            else
            {
                var val = (string)value;
                string pattern = "D";

                var fText = new FormattedString();
                string[] substrings = Regex.Split(val, pattern);

                /* String will be splitted in 3 parts
                    [0] Hello
                    [1] D [Bold]
                    [2] ev! How are you?
                */
                if (substrings != null && substrings.Count() >= 0)
                {
                    fText.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = substrings[0], FontFamily = "RobotoRegular" });
                    fText.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = "D", FontFamily = "RobotoBold" });
                    fText.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = substrings[1], FontFamily = "RobotoRegular" });
                }
                    
                Debug.WriteLine($"Final Formatted Text - {fText}");

                return fText;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Exception - {ex.Message}");
        }

        return (string)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

---

**Declare it in the App.xaml i.e. Resource Dictionary**

```cs
<Application.Resources>
    <!--Converters-->
    <converters:StringToFormattedTextConverter x:Key="StringToFormattedTextConverter" />
</Application.Resources>
```

---

**Use it with Label like this way:**

```cs
<Label HorizontalOptions="Center" 
       VerticalOptions="Start"
       FormattedText="{Binding WelcomeText,
                       Converter={StaticResource StringToFormattedTextConverter}}"/>
```

---

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Okey, glad you have found the solution! Remember to mark your answer when you have time.

Comment: Why? Generally we all can do that in SO.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to put the 'logic' in the ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string StringBeforeBold {get;set;}
    public string StringBold {get;set}
    public string StringAfterBold {get;set;}
}
```

The xaml-Code could be like this

```
<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="{Binding StringBeforeBold}" />
            <Span Text="{Binding StringBold}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            <Span Text="{Binding StringAfterBold}" />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

Comment: This works in my apps. It's also the cleanest solution...

Answer (score 1):

You could custom [LabelRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers) in each platform(Android/iOS) by using [SpannableString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.text.spannablestring?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9)/[NSMutableAttributedString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsmutableattributedstring?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) to achieve that. You could use `Range` from `start` index and `end` index to set where need to set `Bold` for `Label`.

Create a **CustomLabel** in Xamarin Forms:

```
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty StartPositionProperty = BindableProperty.Create("StartPosition", typeof(int), typeof(CustomLabel), null);

    public int StartPosition
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(StartPositionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StartPositionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty EndPositionProperty = BindableProperty.Create("EndPosition", typeof(int), typeof(CustomLabel), null);

    public int EndPosition
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(EndPositionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EndPositionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty BoldLengthProperty = BindableProperty.Create("BoldLength", typeof(int), typeof(CustomLabel), null);

    public int BoldLength
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(BoldLengthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BoldLengthProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Use it in **Xaml** as follows:

```
<local:CustomLabel x:Name="mylabel" 
                    Text="Hello Dev! How are you?" 
                    FontSize="Large"
                    StartPosition="6"
                    EndPosition="7"
                    BoldLength="1"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

Then in **Android** solution to create **CustomLabelRenderer**(Here start and end is hardcode, you could add [Bindable property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) for CustomLabel to make it flexible):

```
public class CustomLabelRenderer: LabelRenderer
{
    public CustomLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        CustomLabel customLabel = e.NewElement as CustomLabel;

        if (Control != null)
        {
            SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(e.NewElement.Text);
            StyleSpan styleSpan_B = new StyleSpan(TypefaceStyle.Bold);
            spannableString.SetSpan(styleSpan_B, customLabel.StartPosition, customLabel.EndPosition, SpanTypes.InclusiveExclusive);
            Control.SetText(spannableString,TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: About `SetSpan` method, second paramater is start, third paramater is end.

The effect:

[image]

In **iOS** solution, also create **CustomLabelRenderer**:

```
public class CustomLabelRenderer: LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        CustomLabel customLabel = e.NewElement as CustomLabel;

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var attributedString = new NSMutableAttributedString(e.NewElement.Text);
            var BoldTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes
            {
                Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica-Bold", 30f)
            };
            attributedString.SetAttributes(BoldTextAttributes.Dictionary, new NSRange(customLabel.StartPosition, customLabel.BoldLength));
            Control.AttributedText = attributedString;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: About `NSRange`, first paramater is start, second paramater is length.

The effect:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can used localized strings using resources like this:

1. Create a .resx file somewhere
2. Add the namespace of the .resx file to your page

```xml
xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:MyApp.Properties"
```

3. Use the resources instead of the hard coded text

```xml
<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="{x:Static loc:Resources.Hello}" />
            <Span Text=" " />
            <Span Text="{x:Static loc:Resources.Dev}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            <Span Text="! " />
            <Span Text="{x:Static loc:Resources.HowAreYou}" />
            <Span Text="?" />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

Comment: Yes, but we can not do it directly from xaml with the way you have mentioned. Because I give the string just of example purpose. In real scenario it will be a specific word in long string. And that I can not split in small parts like this. That is why I have used converter. But still thanks for sharing your idea.

Comment: Ok. Makes sense.